# jQuery Datatables with Dynamic Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a simple messaging system and I am retrieving the messages from the DB using jQuery/AJAX and appending to a table. I wanted pagination for the messages so I opted to use the DataTables plugin (https://datatables.net/).

I am having trouble using this with my dynamically generated data. I also have functions such as "delete message" which would then delete the message and then retrieve the messages again (refresh the table). I am getting the error "cannot re-initialise DataTable".

This is my code so far:

```
function getmessages(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "modules/ajaxgetmessages.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        })
        .success(function(response) {
            if(!response.errors && response.result) {
                $("#tbodymessagelist").html('');
                $.each(response.result, function( index, value) {
                    var messagesubject = value[3];
                    var messagecontent = value[4];
                    var messagetime = value[5];
                    var sendername = value[2];
                    var readstatus = value[7];
                    var messageid = value[8];
                    if (readstatus==0){
                        messageheader += '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="inboxcheckbox input-chk"></td><td class="sendername"><b>'+sendername+'</b></td><td class="messagesubject"><b>'+messagesubject+'</b></td><td><b>'+messagetime+'</b></td><td class="messageid" style="display:none">'+messageid+'</td><td class="readstatus" style="display:none">'+readstatus+'</td><td class="messagecontent" style="display:none"><b>'+messagecontent+'</b></td></tr>';
                    } else {
                        messageheader += '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="inboxcheckbox input-chk"></td><td class="sendername">'+sendername+'</td><td class="messagesubject">'+messagesubject+'</td><td>'+messagetime+'</td><td class="messageid" style="display:none">'+messageid+'</td><td class="readstatus" style="display:none">'+readstatus+'</td><td class="messagecontent" style="display:none"><b>'+messagecontent+'</b></td></tr>';                                                         
                    }
                });
                $("#tbodymessagelist").html(messageheader);
                $('#tblinbox').DataTable({
                    "paging":   true,
                    "ordering": false,
                    "info":     false
                });
            } else {
                $.each(response.errors, function( index, value) {
                    $('input[name*='+index+']').addClass('error').after('<div class="errormessage">'+value+'</div>')
                });
            }
        });     
}
```

So how can I essentially, make changes to my table after message deletion or other functions and then "refresh" the table? It also shows `Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries` in the footer even though there are entries there.

Comment: try `destroy: true`

Comment: There are options in datatables to have ajax - so you can get datatables to do all the heavy stuff, pagination/ordering so you no longer have to load all the rows as one. This will be good in the long run when there are lots of messages.

Answer (score 0):

You must destroy datatable berfore create new instance;

```
          `
           $('#tblinbox').DataTable.destroy();
           $('#tblinbox').empty();
```